# text to list conversion

Tags: c#, list

I have to create a crossword with a given text dictionary.
When I try to convert the text to the list, my `list.Count` shows that the list has 28 elements.
Even if I try `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");` `lines.Length` indicates 28 also.
Here's my code

```
class Dictionnaire
{
    private string langue;

    public List<string> Motspossibles = File.ReadAllLines("MotsFR.txt").ToList();
}
```

Here's a sample of the text file

```
AA AH AI AN AS AU AY BI BU CA CE CI DA DE DO DU EH EN ES ET EU EX FA FI GO HA HE HI HO IF IL IN JE KA LA LE LI LU MA ME MI MU NA NE NI NO NU OC OH ON OR OS OU PI PU RA RE RI RU SA SE SI SU TA TE TU UN US UT VA VE VS VU WU XI
3
AAS ACE ADA ADO AGA AGE AGI AIE AIL AIR AIS AIT ALE ALU AME AMI ANA AND ANE ANS API ARA ARC ARE ARS ART ASA ASE AUX AVE AXA AXE AYS BAC BAH BAI BAL BAN BAR BAS BAT BAU BEA BEC BEE BEL BEN BER BEY BIC BIO BIP BIS BIT BLE BOA BOB BOF BOG BOL BON BOP BOT BOX BOY BRU BUE BUG BUN BUS BUT BYE CAB CAF CAL CAP CAR CAS CEP CES CET CHU CIF CIL CIS CLE COB COI COL CON COQ COR COU CPT CRE CRI CRU CUL CUT DAB DAL DAM DAN DAO DAW DEB DER DES DEY DIA DIN DIS DIT DIX DOC DOL DOM DON DOS DOT DRU DRY DUC DUE DUO DUR DUS DUT EAU ECU EGO ELU EME EMU EON EPI ERE ERG ERS EST ETA ETE EUE EUH EUS EUT EUX FAC FAF FAN FAR FAT FAX FCO FEE FER FEU FEZ FIA FIC FIE FIL FIN FIS FIT FLA FOB FOC FOG FOI FOL FOR FOU FOX FUI FUN FUR FUS FUT GAG GAI GAL GAN GAP GAY GAZ GEL GEO GIN GIS GIT GLU GOI GON GOS GOY GRE GUE GUI GUS GYM HAI HAN HEM HEP HEU HIA HIC HIE HIP HIT HOP HOT HOU HUA HUE HUI HUM HUN IBN IBO ICI IDE IFS ILE ILS ION IPE IRA IRE ISO IVE IXA IXE JAB JAM JAN JAR JAS JET JEU JOB JUS KAN KAS KHI KID KIF KIL KIP KIR KIT KOB KOP KOT KSI KWA KYU LAC LAD LAI LAO LAS LEI LEK LEM LES LET LEU LEV LEZ LIA LIE LIN LIS LIT LOB LOF LOG LOI LOS LOT LUE LUI LUS LUT LUX LYS MAC MAI MAL MAN MAO MAS MAT MAX MEC MEN MEO MER MES MET MIE MIL MIN MIR MIS MIT MIX MOA MOB MOI MOL MON MOS MOT MOU MOX MUA MUE MUR MUS MUT MYE NAY NEE NEF NEM NEO NES NET NEY NEZ NIA NIB NID NIE NIF NIT NOM NON NOS NUA NUE NUI NUL NUS OBI ODE OFF OHE OHM OIE OIL OKA OLA OLE ONC ONT OPE ORE ORS OSA OSE OST OTA OTE OUD OUF OUH OUI OUT OVE OXO OYE PAF PAL PAN PAR PAS PAT PEC PEP PET PEU PFF PHI PIC PIE PIF PIN PIS PIU PLI PLU POP POT POU PRE PRO PSI PST PSY PUA PUB PUE PUR PUS PUT PUY QAT QUE QUI QUO RAB RAC RAD RAI RAM RAP RAS RAT RAY RAZ REA REE REG REM REZ RHE RHO RIA RIE RIF RIO RIS RIT RIZ ROB ROC ROI ROM ROS ROT RUA RUE RUS RUT RUZ RYE SAC SAI SAL SAR SAS SAX SEC SEL SEN SEP SES SET SIC SIL SIR SIS SIX SKA SKI SOC SOI SOL SON SOT SOU SPA SPI SUA SUC SUD SUE SUR SUS SUT TAC TAG TAN TAO TAR TAS TAU TEC TEE TEK TEL TEP TER TES TET TEX THE TIC TIF TIN TIP TIR TOC TOI TOM TON TOP TOT TRI TUA TUB TUE TUF TUS TUT UNE UNI UNS URE USA USE UTE VAL VAN VAR VAS VAU VER VES VET VIA VIE VIF VIL VIN VIS VIT VOL VOS VUE VUS WAX WEB WOK WON WUS YAK YAM YEN YIN YOD YUE ZEE ZEF ZEN ZIG ZIP ZOB ZOE ZOO ZOU ZUT
4
ABAT ABBE ABRI ABUS ACES ACRE ACTE AERA AERE AFIN AGEE AGES AGIO AGIR AGIS AGIT AIDA AIDE AIES AIGU AILE AIMA AIME AINE AIRE AIRS AISE AISY AJUT ALEA ALFA ALLA ALLE ALLO ALOI ALTO AMAS AMEN AMER AMES AMIE AMIS AMOK ANES ANGE ANIS ANON ANSE ANUS AOUT APAX APEX APRE APTE ARAK ARCS ARDU ARES ARIA ARMA ARME ARTS ATRE AUBE AUGE AULX AUNE AURA AUTO AVAL AVEC AVEU AVEZ AVIS AXAI AXAS AXAT AXEE AXEL AXER AXES AXEZ AXIS AYEZ AZUR BABA BABY BACS BAIE BAIL BAIN BAIS BALS BANC BANG BANS BARS BASA BASE BATE BATI BATS BAUX BAVA BAVE BAYA BAYE BEAT BEAU BEBE BECS BEER BEES BEEZ BEKE BENI BERK BETE BEYS BIEN BILE BINZ BISE BITS BIWA BLES BLET BLEU BLOC BOAS BOBS BOCK BODY BOIS BOIT BOLS BOND BONI BONS BOOK BOOM BORD BOTS BOUC BOUE BOUS BOUT BOXA BOXE BOYS BRAS BREF BRIC BRIE BRIK BRIN BRIO BRIS BROC BROU BRUN BRUS BRUT BUEE BUES BUIS BURE BUSE BUTA BUTE BUTS BYTE CADE CADI CAFE CAGE CAID CAKE CALA CALE CALS CAME CAMP CANE CAPE CAPS CARS CARY CASA CASE CAVE CECI CEDA CEDE CELA CENE CENS CENT CEPE CEPS CERF CEUX CHAH CHAI CHAR CHAS CHAT CHEF CHER CHEZ CHIC CHOC CHOU CHUT CIEL CILS CIME CINQ CIRA CIRE CITA CITE CLAM CLAN CLAY CLEF CLES CLIN CLIP CLOS CLOT CLOU CLUB COCO CODA CODE COIN COIS COIT COKE COLA COLS COLT COMA CONE COQS CORS COSY COTA COTE COUD COUP COUR COUS COUT CRAN CREA CREE CRIA CRIC CRIE CRIN CRIS CROC CRUE CRUS CRUT CUBA CUBE CUIR CUIS CUIT CULS CURE CUTI CUVA CUVE CYAN CYME CYON CZAR DADA DAIM DAIS DAME DANS DARD DATA DATE DAUW DAWS DECA DECU DEFI DEJA DELA DEMI DENI DENT DESK DEUX DEYS DIEU DIME DINA DINE DIRA DIRE DISE DITE DITO DITS DOCK DODU DOIS DOIT DOJO DOME DONC DONS DONT DOPA DOPE DORA DORE DORS DORT DOSA DOSE DOTA DOTE DOTS DOUE DOUX DRAP DROP DRUE DRUS DUCS DUEL DUES DUNE DUNK DUOS DUPA DUPE DURA DURE DURS DYKE DYNE EAUX EBAT ECHO ECHU ECOT ECRU ECUS EDAM EDIT EGAL EJET ELAN ELIS ELIT ELLE ELUE ELUS ELUT EMET EMIR EMIS EMIT EMOI EMUE EMUS EMUT EPEE EPIA EPIE EPIS ERES ERGS ERRA ERRE ESSE ETAI ETAL ETAT ETAU ETES ETRE ETUI EUES EXAM EXIL EXIT EXON EXPO EYRA FACE FADE FAIM FAIS FAIT FAIX FAME FANA FANE FAON FARD FARS FART FATS FAUT FAUX FAXA FAXE FEES FELA FELE FEND FERA FERS FERU FETA FETE FETU FEUE FEUX FEVE FIEE FIEF FIEL FIER FIES FIEZ FIGE FILA FILE FILM FILS FINE FINI FINS FISC FIXA FIXE FLAN FLOT FLOU FLUX FOCS FOIE FOIN FOIS FOLK FOND FONT FOOT FORA FORE FORS FORT FOUR FOUS FOXE FRAC FRAI FRET FRIS FRIT FROC FUEL FUIE FUIR FUIS FUIT FULL FUMA FUME FUNK FUSA FUSE FUTE FUTS GAGE GAGS GAIE GAIN GAIS GALA GALE GANG GANT GARA GARE GARS GATA GATE GAVA GAVE GAYS GAZA GAZE GEAI GELA GELE GEMI GENA GENE GENS GERA GERE GINS GIRL GITE GLAS GLUS GNON GOAL GOBA GOBE GOLF GOND GONG GOUT GOYM GOYS GRAS GRAY GREC GRES GRIL GRIS GROG GROS GRUE GUES GUET GUIS GUNZ GYMS HADJ HAIE HAIK HAIR HAIS HAIT HAJE HAKA HALE HALL HALO HARO HASE HATA HATE HAUT HAVE HELA HELE HERE HEUR HIER HIES HIEZ HOME HORS HOTE HOUE HOUX HUEE HUER HUES HUEZ HUIS HUIT HUMA HUME HUNE IBIS IDEE IDEM IDES IKAT ILES ILOT IMBU INCA INDU INNE INOX INSU INUK IODE IONS IOTA IRAI IRAS IREZ IRIS ISBA ISSU ITEM IVRE IWAN IXAI IXAS IXAT IXEE IXER IXES IXEZ IXIA JABS JACK JACO JADE JAIN JAIS JALE JAMS JANS JARD JARS JASA JASE JASS JAVA JAZZ JEAN JEEP JERK JETA JETE JETS JEUN JEUX JEZE JOBS JOIE JOJO JOLI JONC JOTA JOUA JOUE JOUG JOUI JOUR JUBE JUDD JUDO JUGE JUIF JUIN JUMP JUNK JUPE JURA JURE JURY JUTA JUTE KADI KAKI KALE KALI KAMI KANA KANS KAON KAPO KART KATA KAVA KAWA KAWI KEPI KEUF KEUM KHAN KHAT KHOL KICK KIDS KIEF KIFS KIKI KILO KILS KILT KINA KINE KIPS KIRS KITS KIWI KOBS KOKA KOLA KOPS KORA KORE KOTA KOTE KOTO KOTS KRAK KSAR KUNA KURU KVAS KWAS KYAT KYUS LACA LACE LACK LACS LADS LADY LAIC LAID LAIE LAIT LAKH LAMA LAME LAND LAPS LARD LAVA LAVE LAYA LAYE LEGS LEKS LENT LESA LESE LEST LEUR LEVA LEVE LICE LIED LIEE LIEN LIER LIES LIEU LIEZ LIFT LIMA LIME LINO LION LIRA LIRE LISE LITS LOBE LOBS LOGE LOIN LOIR LOIS LONG LOOK LORS LOTE LOTI LOTO LOTS LOUA LOUE LOUP LUES LUGE LUIT LUMP LUNE LUTH LUTZ LUXA LUXE LYNX LYRA LYRE LYSA LYSE MACH MAGE MAIN MAIS MAJE MAKI MALE MALT MAMY MANS MARC MARE MARI MARK MARS MATE MATH MATS MAUX MAXI MAYA MAYE MAZA MAZE MEAT MELA MELE MEME MENA MENE MENS MENT MENU MERE MERS MESS METS MEUS MEUT MEZE MICA MIDI MIEL MIEN MILE MIMA MIME MINA MINE MIRA MIRE MISA MISE MISS MITA MITE MIXA MIXE MODE MOIS MOKA MOKO MOLE MOLY MONT MORD MORS MORT MOTO MOTS MOUD MOUE MOUS MOUT MOXA MOYA MOYE MUEE MUER MUES MUET MUEZ MUGI MULE MUNI MURA MURE MURI MURS MUSC MUSE MUTA MUTE MYES NAGE NAIF NAIN NAIS NAIT NAJA NAYS NAZE NAZI NECK NEES NEFS NEON NERF NETS NEUF NEVE NEWS NEYS NIDS NIEE NIER NIES NIEZ NIXE NOCE NOEL NOIE NOIR NOIX NOMS NORD NOTA NOTE NOUA NOUE NOUS NOYA NOYE NUEE NUES NUEZ NUIS NUIT NULS OBEI OBUS OCRE ODES OEIL OEUF OGRE OHMS OIES OKAS OMET OMIS OMIT ONCE ONDE ONYX ONZE OPTA OPTE OPUS ORAL OREE ORES ORGE ORME ORNA ORNE ORYX OSEE OSER OSES OSEZ OTEE OTER OTES OTEZ OUED OUIE OUIR OURS OUZO OVNI OXER OYAT OYES OYEZ PACK PAGE PAIE PAIN PAIR PAIX PALE PALI PALS PAMA PAME PANE PANS PAON PAPA PAPE PAPY PARA PARC PARE PARI PARS PART PARU PATE PATI PAVA PAVE PAYA PAYE PAYS PEAU PELA PELE PEND PENE PERD PERE PERI PERS PESA PESE PEUR PEUT PEUX PEZE PICS PIED PIES PIEU PIGE PILA PILE PINS PION PIPE PIRE PISE PLAN PLAT PLIA PLIE PLIS PLOT PLUS PLUT PNEU POIL POIS POIX POLE POLI POLO POLY POND PONT POOL POPE PORC PORE PORT POSA POSE POTS POUF POUR POUX POYA PRES PRET PRIA PRIE PRIS PRIT PRIX PSYS PUBS PUCE PUCK PUER PUEZ PUIS PUJA PULL PUMA PUNI PUNK PURE PURS PUYS QATS QUAD QUAI QUEL QUIA QUID QUIZ QUOI RACE RACK RADE RAGE RAID RAIE RAIL RAJA RAKI RALA RALE RAMA RAME RAMI RANG RANZ RAPA RAPE RAPT RARE RASA RASE RATA RATE RATS RAVE RAVI RAYA RAYE RAYS RECU REDU REEL REER REEZ REGI REGS REIN RELU REND RENE REPU REVA REVE REVU RHUM RIDA RIDE RIEN RIES RIEZ RIMA RIME RING RIRA RIRE RITE RIVA RIVE RIXE ROBE ROCK ROCS RODA RODE ROIS ROLE ROLL ROND ROSE ROSI ROTI ROTS ROUE ROUX RUDE RUEE RUER RUES RUEZ RUGI RUSA RUSE RUSH RUTS RYAL RYES SACS SAGA SAGE SAIN SAIS SAIT SAKE SAKI SALA SALE SALI SANA SANG SANS SAPA SAPE SARI SAUF SAUR SAUT SAXE SAXO SCIA SCIE SEAU SECS SEIN SELF SELS SEMA SEME SENS SENT SEPT SERA SERF SERS SERT SETS SEUL SEVE SEVI SEXE SEXY SHAH SHOW SIED SIEN SIKH SILO SILY SIRE SISE SITE SKAI SKAS SKAT SKIA SKIE SKIF SKIN SKIP SKIS SKUA SLIP SLOW SNOB SOCS SODA SOFA SOIE SOIF SOIN SOIR SOIS SOIT SOJA SOLE SOLI SOLO SOLS SONO SONS SONT SORS SORT SOTS SOUK SOUL SOUS SOYA SPOT STAR STEM STOP STUC SUBI SUCA SUCE SUCS SUEE SUER SUES SUEZ SUIE SUIF SUIS SUIT SURE SURF SURS SWAP SYLI TACT TAIE TAIN TAIS TAIT TAKA TALC TALE TANK TANT TAON TAPA TAPE TAPI TARD TARE TARI TATA TATE TAUX TAXA TAXE TAXI TECK TEJU TEKS TELE TELS TEND TENU TEST TETE TETU THES THON THYM TICS TIEN TIGE TILT TINT TIRA TIRE TIRS TOBY TOCS TOGE TOIT TOLE TOME TOND TONS TOPS TORD TORS TORT TORY TOUR TOUS TOUT TOUX TRAC TRAM TRAX TREK TRES TRIA TRIE TRIO TRIS TROC TROP TROT TROU TROY TRUC TSAR TUBA TUBE TUEE TUER TUES TUEZ TUFS TURC TURF TYPA TYPE TYPO TZAR UBAC UNES UNIE UNIR UNIS UNIT UREE URGE URNE USEE USER USES USEZ VAIN VAIS VALS VALU VAMP VANS VASE VAUT VAUX VEAU VECU VELO VELU VEND VENT VENU VERS VERT VETE VETO VETS VETU VEUF VEUT VEUX VEXA VEXE VICE VIDA VIDE VIES VIFS VILE VILS VINS VINT VIOL VIRA VIRE VISA VISE VITE VIVE VOEU VOIE VOIR VOIS VOIT VOIX VOLA VOLE VOLS VOLT VOMI VONT VOTA VOTE VOUA VOUE VOUS VRAC VRAI VUES WALE WALI WASP WATT WEBS WHIG WHIP WITZ WOKS WONS WURM YACK YAKS YAMS YANG YARD YASS YAWL YENS YETI YEUX YEYE YINS YODS YOGA YOGI YOLE YOUP YUAN YUES YUKO ZAIN ZANI ZEBU ZEES ZEFS ZELE ZEND ZENS ZERO ZEST ZETA ZIGS ZINC ZIPS ZIST ZIZI ZOBS ZOES ZONA ZONE ZOOM ZOOS ZOUK ZOZO
```

I tried to use split function but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split

Comment: Notepad is just the application used by users to view text files. It is not the type of the file. Please [edit] your question to show the code using `Split`; you may have been close and just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: beg my pardon, for me a notepad is a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you are wanting to read lines, when you want all text in a list. Here is a method using regex which splits on any whitespace `\s`.

```
var words = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(@"MotsFR.txt"), @"\s+");
```